# sql case statements to compare not equal to with list of condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to write a condition to make sure the condition is not equal to

```
select * from xtable x
inner join ytable y
 on x.column1 =y.column1
inner join ztable z
on y.column2 =z.column2
where x.column4 = 'abc'
and y.column3 <> cast(z.column4 as bit)
and y.column4 = 'xyz'
```

I am getting error at cast because y.column3 has only 0 or 1 values where has z.column4 has more than 0 and 1 value how can i make other values as 0 or 1 depending upon the value.

i sepreatly wrote the select statement to print 0 and 1 depending upon the condition

```
select case z.column4
when 'True' then 1
when 'false' then 0
when 'From: False To True' then 1
when 'From: True to False' then 0
end as status
from ztable z
```

I am not able to incorproate both together, its giving out error if write like below

```
   select * from xtable x
   inner join ytable y
   on x.column1 =y.column1
   inner join ztable z
   on y.column2 =z.column2
   where x.column4 = 'abc'
   and y.column3  <>  (case when z.column4 = 'True' then 1 
   when z.column4 = 'false' then 0
   when z.column4 = 'From: False To True' then 1
   when z.column4 = 'From: True to False' then 0)
   and y.column4 = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but there is a missing `END` in your last query's `CASE`

```
  .....
AND y.column3 <> CASE z.column4 
                      WHEN 'True' THEN 1 
                      WHEN 'false' THEN 0 
                      WHEN 'From: False To True' THEN 1 
                      WHEN 'From: True to False' THEN 0 
                    END      
  .....
```